# Невозможно собрать проект при изменении версии .NET

Tags: .net, c++-cli

Почему не собирается проект который не использует зависимостей выше `.NET 2.0`?

Подумал что стоит изменить версию дабы улучшить совместимость. При этом под `4.0` и выше собирается спокойно.

```
1>Создание кода...
1>.NETFramework,Version=v4.0.AssemblyAttributes.cpp
1>yami.vlc.vcxproj -> C:\Users\Yami\source\repos\yami\Debug\yami.vlc.dll
1>Сборка проекта "yami.vlc.vcxproj" завершена.
========== Перестроение всех проектов: успешно: 1, с ошибками: 0, пропущено: 0 ==========
```

После смены версии:

```
1>Создание кода...
1>MSVCMRTD.lib(mstartup.obj) : error LNK2022: ёсющ юяхЁрЎшш ё ьхЄрфрээ√ьш (80131195): ═хёютьхёЄшь√х юёюс√х рЄЁшсєЄ√. (0x0c0001fb).
1>MSVCMRTD.lib(mstartup.obj) : error LNK2022: ёсющ юяхЁрЎшш ё ьхЄрфрээ√ьш (80131195): ═хёютьхёЄшь√х юёюс√х рЄЁшсєЄ√. (0x0c000200).
1>MSVCMRTD.lib(managdeh.obj) : error LNK2022: ёсющ юяхЁрЎшш ё ьхЄрфрээ√ьш (80131195): ═хёютьхёЄшь√х юёюс√х рЄЁшсєЄ√. (0x0c0000db).
1>MSVCMRTD.lib(managdeh.obj) : error LNK2022: ёсющ юяхЁрЎшш ё ьхЄрфрээ√ьш (80131195): ═хёютьхёЄшь√х юёюс√х рЄЁшсєЄ√. (0x0c0000de).
1>MSVCMRTD.lib(mehvecdtr.obj) : error LNK2022: ёсющ юяхЁрЎшш ё ьхЄрфрээ√ьш (80131195): ═хёютьхёЄшь√х юёюс√х рЄЁшсєЄ√. (0x0c0000b4).
1>MSVCMRTD.lib(mehvecdtr.obj) : error LNK2022: ёсющ юяхЁрЎшш ё ьхЄрфрээ√ьш (80131195): ═хёютьхёЄшь√х юёюс√х рЄЁшсєЄ√. (0x0c0000b7).
1>MSVCMRTD.lib(msilexit.obj) : error LNK2022: ёсющ юяхЁрЎшш ё ьхЄрфрээ√ьш (80131195): ═хёютьхёЄшь√х юёюс√х рЄЁшсєЄ√. (0x0c000103).
1>MSVCMRTD.lib(msilexit.obj) : error LNK2022: ёсющ юяхЁрЎшш ё ьхЄрфрээ√ьш (80131195): ═хёютьхёЄшь√х юёюс√х рЄЁшсєЄ√. (0x0c000108).
1>MSVCMRTD.lib(pureMSILcode.obj) : error LNK2022: ёсющ юяхЁрЎшш ё ьхЄрфрээ√ьш (80131195): ═хёютьхёЄшь√х юёюс√х рЄЁшсєЄ√. (0x0c0001b8).
1>MSVCMRTD.lib(pureMSILcode.obj) : error LNK2022: ёсющ юяхЁрЎшш ё ьхЄрфрээ√ьш (80131195): ═хёютьхёЄшь√х юёюс√х рЄЁшсєЄ√. (0x0c0001ba).
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1255: эх єфрыюё№ т√яюыэшЄ№ ъюьяюэютъє шч-чр ю°шсюъ т ьхЄрфрээ√ї
1>Сборка проекта "yami.vlc.vcxproj" завершена с ошибкой.
========== Сборка: успешно: 0, с ошибками: 1, без изменений: 0, пропущено: 0 ==========
```

Но если посмотреть на свойства зависимости `mscorlib` то он продолжает линковаться на 4 версию.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как разрешить данную ситуацию?

Comment: Там есть параметр Platform Toolset в свойствах проекта, который должен соответствовать версии NET (для 2.0 вроде v90 должен быть). Вам предстоит увлекательный квест "догадайся, как это называется в русской локализации студии"

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight: Хм, а это какой пакет SDK надо поставить дабы там появился v90?

Comment: Предположительно вот этот: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18950 А какая версия студии? С теми тулсетами, которые уже есть, ни с одним не работает?

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight: 2017, но там стоит Win10 SDK и Win8. Да с другими тулсетами тоже не собирается.

Comment: Возможно, еще понадобится VS2008 поставить, чтобы это провернуть. Вот здесь описано, как для VS2015 это делали: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34905488/using-v90-vs2008-platform-toolset-in-visual-studio-2015